# How to interpret cpuid's page size information about TLB

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, ubuntu-14.04, paging, tlb

I have used the `cpuid | grep -i tlb` command on the terminal to try to determine the exact number of page table entries (and the corresponding page-sizes) being used by the machine. This is what I've got.

```
cache and TLB information (2):
      0x63: data TLB: 1G pages, 4-way, 4 entries
      0x03: data TLB: 4K pages, 4-way, 64 entries
      0x76: instruction TLB: 2M/4M pages, fully, 8 entries
      0xb5: instruction TLB: 4K, 8-way, 64 entries
   L1 TLB/cache information: 2M/4M pages & L1 TLB (0x80000005/eax):
   L1 TLB/cache information: 4K pages & L1 TLB (0x80000005/ebx):
   L2 TLB/cache information: 2M/4M pages & L2 TLB (0x80000006/eax):
   L2 TLB/cache information: 4K pages & L2 TLB (0x80000006/ebx):
   cache and TLB information (2):
      0x63: data TLB: 1G pages, 4-way, 4 entries
      0x03: data TLB: 4K pages, 4-way, 64 entries
      0x76: instruction TLB: 2M/4M pages, fully, 8 entries
      0xb5: instruction TLB: 4K, 8-way, 64 entries
   L1 TLB/cache information: 2M/4M pages & L1 TLB (0x80000005/eax):
   L1 TLB/cache information: 4K pages & L1 TLB (0x80000005/ebx):
   L2 TLB/cache information: 2M/4M pages & L2 TLB (0x80000006/eax):
   L2 TLB/cache information: 4K pages & L2 TLB (0x80000006/ebx):
   cache and TLB information (2):
      0x63: data TLB: 1G pages, 4-way, 4 entries
      0x03: data TLB: 4K pages, 4-way, 64 entries
      0x76: instruction TLB: 2M/4M pages, fully, 8 entries
      0xb5: instruction TLB: 4K, 8-way, 64 entries
   L1 TLB/cache information: 2M/4M pages & L1 TLB (0x80000005/eax):
   L1 TLB/cache information: 4K pages & L1 TLB (0x80000005/ebx):
   L2 TLB/cache information: 2M/4M pages & L2 TLB (0x80000006/eax):
   L2 TLB/cache information: 4K pages & L2 TLB (0x80000006/ebx):
   cache and TLB information (2):
      0x63: data TLB: 1G pages, 4-way, 4 entries
      0x03: data TLB: 4K pages, 4-way, 64 entries
      0x76: instruction TLB: 2M/4M pages, fully, 8 entries
      0xb5: instruction TLB: 4K, 8-way, 64 entries
   L1 TLB/cache information: 2M/4M pages & L1 TLB (0x80000005/eax):
   L1 TLB/cache information: 4K pages & L1 TLB (0x80000005/ebx):
   L2 TLB/cache information: 2M/4M pages & L2 TLB (0x80000006/eax):
   L2 TLB/cache information: 4K pages & L2 TLB (0x80000006/ebx):
```

I wanted to know whether I can interpret this information to say that my data TLB on all the processors (I have a Intel® Core™ i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz with 4 cores) has a Level 1 with 1G pages and 4 entries, and a level 2 with 4K pages and 64 entries? The part that I am confused about is how to make the distinction between these two pieces of information :

```
      0x63: data TLB: 1G pages, 4-way, 4 entries
      0x03: data TLB: 4K pages, 4-way, 64 entries
      0x76: instruction TLB: 2M/4M pages, fully, 8 entries
      0xb5: instruction TLB: 4K, 8-way, 64 entries

   L1 TLB/cache information: 2M/4M pages & L1 TLB (0x80000005/eax):
   L1 TLB/cache information: 4K pages & L1 TLB (0x80000005/ebx):
   L2 TLB/cache information: 2M/4M pages & L2 TLB (0x80000006/eax):
   L2 TLB/cache information: 4K pages & L2 TLB (0x80000006/ebx):
```

Does my TLB has 1G, 4K pages in addition to having 2M pages (as specified in the second paragraph) ? Am I reading this in a completely incorrect way ?